# Using Java streams to group a collection

Tags: java, java-stream

I meet some difficulties to find a pretty written code that does the following stuff (The following use case is just an example):

Use case:

I have students, each student has a collection of books.
For each book, I need to know which student has it.
Note that a book can be owned by multiple students.

Code:
I have a `Set<Student>` as input,
I need to create a `Map<Book, Set<Student>>` as output.

---

I know how to do it not using lambda & streams, but I want to learn how to use it.

Currently, I've created a intermediate internal class (Tuple(Book,Student)) to achieve it, but it looks dirty and I got a `Map<Book, Tuple<Book, Student>>` that does not fit perfectly my needs.

```
students.parallelStream()
    .flatMap(student-> student.getBooks().parallelStream()
        .map(book -> new Tuple(book, student)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(tuple-> tuple.book, Collectors.toSet()))
```

Comment: what is the expected output does it `Map<Book, List<Student>>`?

Comment: Ideally a `Map<Book, Set<Student>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Collectors.mapping` to transform the tuple during collection:

```
Map<Book, Set<Student>> result = students.parallelStream()
        .flatMap(student -> student.getBooks()
                                .parallelStream()
                                .map(book -> new Tuple(book, student)))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(tuple -> tuple.book,
                Collectors.mapping(tuple -> tuple.student, Collectors.toSet())));
```